# JOOQ problem with mapping (DataTypeException)

Tags: java, sql, spring, database, jooq

I get this exception when mapping record to entity:

```
org.jooq.exception.DataTypeException: No Converter found for types java.util.UUID and java.util.List
at org.jooq.impl.Tools.converterOrFail(Tools.java:1208) ~[jooq-3.15.0.jar:na]
at org.jooq.impl.Tools.converterOrFail(Tools.java:1217) ~[jooq-3.15.0.jar:na]
at org.jooq.impl.AbstractRecord.get(AbstractRecord.java:351) ~[jooq-3.15.0.jar:na]
at org.jooq.impl.DefaultRecordMapper$ImmutablePOJOMapper.set(DefaultRecordMapper.java:1146) ~[jooq-3.15.0.jar:na]
at org.jooq.impl.DefaultRecordMapper$ImmutablePOJOMapper.mapNonnested(DefaultRecordMapper.java:1137) ~[jooq-3.15.0.jar:na]
at org.jooq.impl.DefaultRecordMapper$ImmutablePOJOMapper.map(DefaultRecordMapper.java:1124) ~[jooq-3.15.0.jar:na]
at org.jooq.impl.DefaultRecordMapper.map(DefaultRecordMapper.java:610) ~[jooq-3.15.0.jar:na]
at org.jooq.impl.DelayedRecordMapper.map(DelayedRecordMapper.java:69) ~[jooq-3.15.0.jar:na]
at org.jooq.RecordMapper.apply(RecordMapper.java:80) ~[jooq-3.15.0.jar:na]
at org.jooq.RecordMapper.apply(RecordMapper.java:65) ~[jooq-3.15.0.jar:na]
at java.base/java.util.stream.Collectors.lambda$mapping$13(Collectors.java:469) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$3ReducingSink.accept(ReduceOps.java:169) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1845) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:921) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682) ~[na:na]
at org.jooq.impl.AbstractCursor.collect(AbstractCursor.java:78) ~[jooq-3.15.0.jar:na]
at org.jooq.impl.ResultQueryTrait.collect(ResultQueryTrait.java:358) ~[jooq-3.15.0.jar:na]
at org.jooq.impl.ResultQueryTrait.fetchInto(ResultQueryTrait.java:1423) ~[jooq-3.15.0.jar:na]
at com.example.jooqsample.posts.JOOQPostRepository.getAll(JOOQPostRepository.java:45) ~[classes/:na]
at com.example.jooqsample.posts.PostFacade.getAllPosts(PostFacade.java:34) ~[classes/:na]
at com.example.jooqsample.posts.rest.PostController.getAllPosts(PostController.java:27) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1071) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:964) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:670) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:4.0.FR]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:779) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:4.0.FR]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1789) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

Entities:

```java
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PACKAGE)
@Getter
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = "id")
class Post {

    private UUID id;

    private String content;

    private Instant createdAt;

    private List<Comment> comments;

PostDTO toDTO() {
    return PostDTO
            .builder()
            .id(this.id)
            .content(this.content)
            .comments(this.comments.stream().map(Comment::toDTO).toList())
            .build();
    }
 }

@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PACKAGE)
@Getter
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = "id")
class Comment {
    private UUID id;

    private String content;

    private Instant createdAt;

    UUID postId;

CommentDTO toDTO() {
    return new CommentDTO(this.id, this.content);
  }
}
```

Method:

```java
public List<Post> getAll() {
    return dslContext
            .select()
            .from(POSTS)
            .leftJoin(COMMENTS)
            .onKey()
            .fetchInto(Post.class);
}
```

- JOOQ version: 3.15
- Spring Boot version: 2.7.5
- Java version: 17

Comment: you are trying to map Post's comments to Comment's postId. those are different types. check your mapping again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Lukas Eder

I've written this method using multisetAgg. It works ok but i'm not sure it should look like this:

```
  List<Post> getAllPost() {
    List<Post> result =
            dslContext
                    .select(
                            POSTS.ID,
                            POSTS.CONTENT,
                            POSTS.CREATED_AT,
                            multisetAgg(
                                    COMMENTS.ID, COMMENTS.CONTENT, COMMENTS.CREATED_AT, COMMENTS.POST_ID

                            ).as("comments").convertFrom(r -> r.into(Comment.class))
                    )
                    .from(POSTS)
                    .leftJoin(COMMENTS).on(COMMENTS.POST_ID.eq(POSTS.ID))
                    .groupBy(POSTS.ID)
                    .fetchInto(Post.class);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Why your approach doesn't work

You're creating a flat result set from your one-to-many relationship between `POSTS` and `COMMENTS`, and then, you're expecting jOOQ's [`DefaultRecordMapper`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DefaultRecordMapper.html) (via the `fetchInto(Class)` method) to de-duplicate those flat results again automatically for you. But that's not how things work in jOOQ. While *you* know the relationship between `POSTS` and `COMMENTS` in your query, a flat jOOQ `Result` does not. There's no obvious way how to auto-deduplicate stuff. Imagine, you had several nested collections in `Post`, how would that even work?

#### Using `MULTISET` to nest collections

The most jOOQ and SQL idiomatic way to nest collections is to use [`MULTISET`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/multiset-value-constructor/), along with [ad-hoc converters](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/fetching/ad-hoc-converter/), e.g. like this:

```java
List<Post> result =
dslContext
    .select(
        POSTS.ID,
        POSTS.CONTENT,
        POSTS.CREATED_AT,
        multiset(
            select(COMMENTS.ID, COMMENTS.CONTENT, COMMENTS.CREATED_AT)
            .from(COMMENTS)
            .where(COMMENTS.POST_ID.eq(POSTS.ID))
        ).convertFrom(r -> r.map(Records.mapping(Comment::new))))
    .from(POSTS)
    .fetch(Records.mapping(Post::new));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but now i get this exception: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Column "PUBLIC.POSTS.ID" not found

Comment: @Sampeteq: Ah that's been addressed in jOOQ 3.18 for dialects like H2: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/12045. The workaround is to use `multisetAgg()` for the time being.

Comment: I've tried to use multisetAgg() but it event doesn't compile

Comment: @Sampeteq: Well, it seems you're on jOOQ 3.15.0, but the current version is 3.17.5, so might try upgrading first. I'll be happy to answer follow-up questions about compilation errors, though... Better not in the comments, there isn't enough space for this.

Comment: I've added comment with written method using multisetAgg

Comment: I'm sorry, not comment but answer. It's on bottom. MultisetAgg works fine thanks for your help